# how can i use Dll function in qt

Tags: c, qt, dll

how can i use this dll function?:

```
extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) 
  void   __cdecl InvertRawPic(unsigned char *In, unsigned char *Out, 
                              unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols);
```

in QT. This function is to invert images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically load your library at runtime, you have 2 ways:
 
1) using platform-specific API (for Windows it is functions like LoadLibrary(...), GetProcAddress(...)); 
2) using QLibrary class, which just cross-platform Qt wrapper to do such things. 
Both of this methods require from you to specify functions names to methods like GetProceAddress() or QLibrary::resolve()...
Qt also has plugin system, but it is not appropriate for side-created dlls...

This is working example from my code:

```
// it is body of "bool func()" function...
typedef DWORD (*SetSystemMemFuncPtr_t)(DWORD dwStorePages);
SetSystemMemFuncPtr_t SetSystemMemoryDivision;
```

HMODULE hLib        = 0;
LPCWSTR libName     = L"coredll.dll";
LPCWSTR procName    = L"SetSystemMemoryDivision";

if(!(hLib = LoadLibrary(libName)))
{
    return false;
}

if(!(SetSystemMemoryDivision = reinterpret_cast(GetProcAddress(hLib, procName))))
{
        return false;
}
// do some work...
FreeLibrary(hLib);